# passing button name as a string

Tags: java, jbutton

Create reference to existing object from value of string in java

In my project, there are many buttons (currently its around 70); each button brings up a question in jlabel from database.
Now there will be colors assigned to each button (jButton from swings precisely) depending on user selection whether he want to review the questions or not, or he has marked the answer of the question or not.

One way is to code for each jbutton's actionperformed and use if-else in each of them to get the exact color and then use the setBackground property to change it to specific color.
But this leads to great problems if code has to be changed slightly. Then I have to copy the changes in each of those 70 buttons, which may increase in future.

What I am thinking is a way to create a function and pass string parameter containing name of button.
So it will be:
void selectfromdatabase(String buttonname) 
{
    //(.).setBackground(Color.yellow);     <= This is what I need
}
So now if buttonname has value jButton1, the resultant command will be jButton1.setBackground(Color.yellow);

I have referred to some SO forums and I found something called Reflection. But acc to my knowledge till now, it will work only in case of methods and not in object. Or am I missing something???

Comment: You could try a map `Map<String, JButton>`. This can contain all buttons and they will be identified by their name. If you write `map.get(name)` you will receive your button object with that name or null if this name is not known.

Comment: You can create a method with 2 parameters, and pass 1st as the button name, as changeColor('btnName',Color.Yellow), that can be worked out with reflection easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something called an actionCommand for an ActionEvent tpye object. When you bind each button to your ActionListener, you set a string parameter(actionCommand) for each. Then you can access that paramerer in onActionPerformed and distinguish the source of the event.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    JButton btn1 = new JButton("btn1");
    btn1.setActionCommand("btn1");

    JButton btn2 = new JButton("btn2");
    btn2.setActionCommand("btn2");

    btn1.addActionListener(this);
    btn2.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    String sourceBtn = ae.getActionCommand();
    System.out.println(sourceBtn + "Button pressed!");
}
```